# From on hold to closed with out explanations

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I could understand the closing of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412766/exploding-lines-with-two-types-delimiters) if I hadn't done anything, because it wasn't posted very clearly, so I significalty reworded my question. What do I have to do, post it again?

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Questions move from On Hold to Closed automatically after 5 days. It is merely a name change.

Comment: Reposting the text of the question here isn't particularly productive.  A link would be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I'm not familiar, it's the first time I use a site like Stackoverflow but I now understand more how it works. At first I thought I had to be specific with my question. I reworded my question and posted a comment but it didn't help, so I will try to contact the persons who put my question on hold at first.
Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Editing an on-hold question automatically adds it to a reopen queue. If 5 people who see it agree that it has been reworded into an appropriate question, it will be reopened. If not, it will stay closed. You can continue to edit it in the hopes of improving it enough. If you got any comments on the question, be sure to take them into account as you edit.

You have added code and at a first glance it seems like your question should be re-opened, but several unaddressed comments suggest that there is no code that can meet your requirements. You will need to clarify the issues they're raising, and then flag your question and ask for it to be reopened. More details are in [the help centre](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions).